# How to reuse the validation method written for mat datepicker in other components

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-datepicker

In my component i have 2 date pickers and there is start date and end date validation . This method checks whether start date is before end date . This validation will be applicable for all the date pickers . How to reuse the validations in other components instead of writing the same logic again and again in other components.

**searchOrder.ts**

```
comparisonEnddateValidator(): any {
    let ldStartDate = this.formGroup.value['covstartdate'];
    let ldEndDate = this.formGroup.value['covenddate'];

    let startnew = new Date(ldStartDate);
    let endnew = new Date(ldEndDate);
    if (startnew > endnew) {
      return this.formGroup.controls['covenddate'].setErrors({ 'invaliddaterange': true });
    }

    let oldvalue = startnew;
    this.formGroup.controls['covstartdate'].reset();
    this.formGroup.controls['covstartdate'].patchValue(oldvalue);
    return this.formGroup.controls['covstartdate'].setErrors({ 'invaliddaterange': false });
  }

  comparisonStartdateValidator(): any {
    let ldStartDate = this.formGroup.value['covstartdate'];
    let ldEndDate = this.formGroup.value['covenddate'];

    let startnew = new Date(ldStartDate);
    let endnew = new Date(ldEndDate);
    if (startnew > endnew) {
      return this.formGroup.controls['covstartdate'].setErrors({ 'invaliddaterange': true });
    }

    let oldvalue = endnew;
    this.formGroup.controls['covenddate'].reset();
    this.formGroup.controls['covenddate'].patchValue(oldvalue);
    return this.formGroup.controls['covenddate'].setErrors({ 'invaliddaterange': false });
  }
```

**searchOrder.html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label> Covering Start Date </mat-label>
    <input
      matInput
      [matDatepicker]="CovStartdate"
      formControlName="covstartdate"
      (dateChange)="comparisonStartdateValidator()"
      required
    />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle
      matSuffix
      [for]="CovStartdate"
    ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #CovStartdate></mat-datepicker>
    <mat-error
      *ngIf="
        formGroup.controls['covstartdate'].hasError('invaliddaterange')
      "
    >
      <strong>Start date cannot be greater than end date</strong>
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error
      *ngIf="formGroup.controls['covstartdate'].hasError('required')"
    >
      Covering Start date is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label> Covering End Date </mat-label>
    <input
      matInput
      [matDatepicker]="CovEnddate"
      formControlName="covenddate"
      (dateChange)="comparisonEnddateValidator()"
      required
    />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle
      matSuffix
      [for]="CovEnddate"
    ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #CovEnddate></mat-datepicker>
    <mat-error
      *ngIf="formGroup.controls['covenddate'].hasError('invaliddaterange')"
    >
      <strong>End date cannot be earlier than start date</strong>
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error
      *ngIf="formGroup.controls['covenddate'].hasError('required')"
    >
      Covering End date is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: make a service and use it in whole application.

Comment: @najam Thanks for your response . Can you pls be more elaborate .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a service. Then create a generic validator function that validates the date pickers.

**shared.service.ts**

```js
comparisonEnddateValidator(formGroup, startControlName, endControlName): any {
    let ldStartDate = formGroup.value[startControlName];
    let ldEndDate = formGroup.value[endControlName];

    let startnew = new Date(ldStartDate);
    let endnew = new Date(ldEndDate);
    if (startnew > endnew) {
        formGroup.controls[endControlName].setErrors({
            invaliddaterange: true
        });
        return formGroup;
    }

    let oldvalue = startnew;
    formGroup.controls[startControlName].reset();
    formGroup.controls[startControlName].patchValue(oldvalue);
    formGroup.controls[startControlName].setErrors({
        invaliddaterange: false
    });

    return formGroup;
}
```

then call this function from your components -

**app.component.ts**

```js
comparisonEnddateValidator(): any {
    this.formGroup = 
        this.sharedService.comparisonEnddateValidator(this.formGroup, 'covstartdate', 'covenddate');
    }
}
```

Comment: you needn't use a service. You can simple create a .ts with the function (remember write "export": `export function comparisonEnddateValidator(..){...}` so you can simple `import {comparisonEndvateValidator} from './utils/comparisonEnddateValidator.ts'`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directive for the case handling and reusing the code. That's the best way to reuse the components. You can write the whole logic in that component itself and reuse anywhere you need.

```
<date-picker {... pass your conditions or data here.} 
             [condition]="startDate"
             [value]="startDataValue">
<date-picker>
```

Your directive can contain this

HTML file

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Ts File

```
/** @Date picker directive with parent data passed for validations and values */

@Component({
  selector: 'date-picker',
  templateUrl: 'your template name',
})
export class DatePicker {
  @Input() minDate: Date = null;
  @Input() maxDate: Date = null;

  constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: I thought of creating a component but each datepicker has different date range and different set of validation.  So thought of reusing the method.  Can you give an example how to create it as directive

Comment: Date ranges you can pass as the data props. [minDate]="this.minDate". You can pass what ever data you need and bind the value in the directive